Does the Tanakh ever say that the covenant of Moses is eternal or everlasting?
Forgive me for my ignorance, I am a fairly new convert to the Jewish faith and I have only recently started investigating the Jewish faith, Jews obviously believe that the covenant of Moses is eternal and never ends, but does the Tanakh ever explicitly say that the covenant of Moses is eternal?

I am a fairly new convert to the Jewish faith and I have only recently started investigating the Jewish faith. Usually the process works the other way around.

No, it doesn't.  This is because the word עולם can mean age in addition to eternity and elsewhere where it's typically translated "forever" it actually says לדרתיכם which could mean "of your generations" or "for [the sake of] your generations" or whatever "to your generations" means.

Which specific covenant are you referring to?

It is the plain meaning of many verses in the Bible, which speak of commandments to teach our children and our children's children, and that many commandments apply "for your generations". By a quick search on Sefaria I found 27.
It is specifically laid out by Moses in Deuteronomy Ch. 4:

Now therefore hearken, O Yisra᾽el, to the statutes and to the judgments, which I teach you, to do them, that you may live, and go in and possess the land which the Lord God of your fathers gives you.
You shall not add to the word which I command you, neither shall you diminish from it, that you may keep the commandments of the Lord your God which I command you... Behold, I have taught you statutes and judgments, even as the Lord my God commanded me, that you should act accordingly in the land whither you go to possess it.
Keep them therefore and do them; for this is your wisdom and your understanding in the sight of the nations, who shall hear all these statutes, and say, Surely this great nation is a wise and understanding people.
For what nation is there so great, that has God so near to them, as the Lord our God is in all things that we call upon him for?
And what nation is there so great, that has statutes and judgments so righteous as all this Tora, which I set before you this day?
Only take heed to thyself, and keep thy soul diligently, lest thou forget the things which thy eyes have seen, and lest they depart from thy heart all the days of thy life: but teach them thy sons, and thy sons’ sons—
the day that thou stoodest before the Lord thy God in Ḥorev, when the Lord said to me, Gather me the people together, and I will make them hear my words, that they may learn to fear me all the days that they shall live upon the earth, and that they may teach their children.
And you came near and stood under the mountain; and the mountain burned with fire to the heart of heaven, with darkness, clouds, and thick darkness.
And the Lord spoke to you out of the midst of the fire: you heard the voice of the words, but saw no form; only a voice.
And he declared to you his covenant, which he commanded you to perform...
But the Lord has taken you, and brought you out of the iron furnace, out of Miżrayim, to be to him a people of inheritance, as you are this day.
But the Lord was angry with me for your sakes, and swore that I should not go over the Yarden, and that I should not go in to that good land, which the Lord thy God gives thee for an inheritance:
but I must die in this land, I must not go over the Yarden: but you shall go over, and possess that good land.
**Take heed to yourselves, lest you forget the covenant of the Lord your God, which he made with you, and make you a carved idol, or the likeness of anything, which the Lord thy God has forbidden thee.
For the Lord thy God is a consuming fire, a jealous God.
When thou shalt beget children, and children’s children, and you shall have remained long in the land, and shall deal corruptly, and make a carved idol, the likeness of anything, and shall do evil in the sight of the Lord thy God, to provoke him to anger:
I call heaven and earth to witness against you this day, that you shall soon utterly perish from off the land into which you go over the Yarden to possess it; you shall not prolong your days upon it, but shall utterly be destroyed.
And the Lord shall scatter you among the nations, and you shall be left few in number among the nations, where the Lord shall lead you.
And there you shall serve gods, the work of men’s hands, wood and stone, which neither see, nor hear, nor eat, nor smell.
But if from there thou shalt seek the Lord thy God, thou shalt find him, if thou seek him with all thy heart and with all thy soul.
When thou art in distress, and all these things are come upon thee, in the latter days, if thou turn to the Lord thy God, and art obedient to his voice;
(for the Lord thy God is a merciful God;) he will not forsake thee, nor will he destroy thee, nor forget the covenant of thy fathers which he swore to them.
For ask now of the days that are past, which were before thee, since the day that God created man upon the earth, and from the one side of heaven to the other, whether there has been any such thing as this great thing is, or whether aught has been heard like it?
Did ever people hear the voice of God speaking out of the midst of the fire, as thou hast heard, and live?
Or has God ventured to go and take him a nation from the midst of another nation, by trials, by signs, and by wonders, and by war, and by a mighty hand, and by a stretched out arm, and by great terrors, according to all that the Lord your God did for you in Miżrayim before your eyes?
To thee it was shown, that thou mightest know that the Lord he is God; there is none else beside him.
Out of heaven he made thee hear his voice, that he might instruct thee: and upon earth he showed thee his great fire; and thou didst hear his words out of the midst of the fire.
And because he loved thy fathers, therefore, he chose their seed after them, and brought thee out, he himself being present, with his mighty power out of Miżrayim;
to drive out nations from before thee greater and mightier than thou art, to bring thee in, to give thee their land for an inheritance, as it is this day.
Know therefore this day, and consider it in thy heart, that the Lord he is God in heaven above, and upon the earth beneath: there is no other.
Thou shalt keep therefore his statutes, and his commandments, which I command thee this day, that it may go well with thee, and with thy children after thee, and that thou mayst prolong thy days upon the earth, which the Lord thy God gives thee, for ever.

This is also the closing message of the last of the prophets, Malachi (ch. 3):

Then they who feared the Lord spoke to one another: and the Lord hearkened, and heard it, and a book of remembrance was written before him for those who feared the Lord, and took heed of his name.
And they shall be mine, says the Lord of hosts, on that day which I appoint as my particular day; and I will spare them, as a man spares his own son who serves him.
Then you shall return, and see the difference between the righteous and the wicked, between him that serves God and him that does not serve him.
For, behold, that day is coming; it burns like a furnace; and all the arrogant, and all who do wickedly, shall be stubble: and the day that is coming shall burn them up, says the Lord of hosts, so that it will leave them neither root nor branch.
But to you who fear my name the sun of righteousness shall arise with healing in its wings; and you shall go out, and leap like calves from the stall.
And you shall tread down the wicked; for they shall be ashes under the soles of your feet on the day that I do this, says the Lord of hosts. Remember the Tora of Moshe my servant, which I commanded him in Ḥorev for all Yisra᾽el, both statutes and judgments.
Behold, I will send you Eliyya, the prophet, before the coming of the great and dreadful day of the Lord:
and he shall turn the heart of the fathers to the children, and the heart of the children to their fathers, lest I come and smite the land with a curse.

Malachi describes the final day of judgement in history, and says to remember the Torah of Moshe until that day, for those that do will be rewarded, and those that don't will be punished. This means that the Torah is binding until the end of time, with the return of Elijah the prophet. This message is specifically chosen as the end of the words of the prophets. In a way, it is G-d's final direct message to us.
